# Bitbucket Cloud API: is there a way to edit a file in a repo?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

The Bitbucket Server API documentation [outlines an endpoint to submit a PUT request and edit a file](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v806/api-group-repository/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-browse-path-put) within a specified repository. However, the Bitbucket Cloud API does not seem to have this same functionality included.

Is there a direct or indirect way to edit a file using Bitbucket Cloud API?

My specific use case is to bump the version number specified within a build pipeline YAML file each time a successful Production release happens.

The current Python template provided for the Bitbucket Server API is as follows:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://{baseurl}/rest/api/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path}"

headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "PUT",
   url,
   headers=headers
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

However, the Cloud API base URL is obviously different and it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The work around for this on the Bitbucket Cloud API was to:

1. [GET the original file](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-source/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-src-commit-path-get) that I want to edit
2. Write the contents of this file to a new empty file with the same name
3. Edit the contents of the file to suit my needs
4. [POST the edited file](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-source/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-src-post) (Posting a file with the same name to the same location causes an overwrite of the original)

Things to note:

- I used Python to write my script, using the Requests library for the HTTP calls and a couple other libraries to parse the file as needed.
- My script committed directly to the main branch. In order to do so, you need to ensure that you are not blocked by any branching restrictions. I had to create an exception for the CI account we use to do any automation tasks like this.